# Disable/Hide unnecessary inline forms in django admin

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have model 'Product' model and many other model which have their foreign key as Product.
Currently I have ProductAdmin line this

```
class Product:
    type_of_product=models.ChoiceField()

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductAdminForm
    inlines = [Inline1, Inline2, Inline3, Inline4,....Inline 15]
```

So the Product admin add page is looking very big form. Here I need to fill only some of the models inlines depending on the value of type_of_product. So many entries of inline models are empty.

So essentially inlines are related to type_of_product attribute of Product. Current the user has to take care in which inlines he has to fill values according to what he chose as type_of_product.

Now I want to sort this out.

Option 1)
Dynamic rendering of inlines forms according to what user has chosen as type_of_product through AJAX.(No idea how to do it)

Option 2)
Disable or hide the unnecessary inlines so he can't see the inline forms of unrelated models.

Can anyone help to sort this out.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify inlines depending on current object, just override `change_view` method of `ModelAdmin`. In your `ProductAdmin` add something like this:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=object_id)
    current_inlines = []
    # CODE TO FILL INLINES BASED ON PRODUCT
    self.inlines = current_inlines
    return super(ProductAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also thought implementing this way but I want to do it dynamically. SO initially when the Product admin is loaded all the inlines should be there but when user selects type_of _field attribute of Product other irrelevant inlines should get hide.

I have fixed mapping for type_of_field vs inlines to display

Comment: OK, so if you want to do it this way you'll have to extend default template for this particular app and add some JavaScript to hide inline groups when `type_of_product` changes. Each inline have unique ID (like `INLINE-MODEL_set-group`) so it should be fairly easy.